# Angular2localization does not get locale data

Tags: angular, localization, format, ionic2, currency

@robisim74 Hi,

I'm trying to implement Angular2localization in my new Ionic 2 (rc0) app.
I need to translate messages and to format dates, numbers, percents and money numbers.

I'm trying to get currentCurrency to put it in currency pipe in html templates.

But `getCurrentCurrency()` always return an empty string.

Here is what I've tried so far:

app.module.ts:

```
import { LocaleModule, LocalizationModule } from 'angular2localization';
...
@NgModule({
  declarations: [...],
  imports: [
    IonicModule.forRoot(MyApp),
    LocaleModule.forRoot(),             // New instance of LocaleService.
    LocalizationModule.forRoot()    // New instance of LocalizationService.
  ],
  bootstrap: [IonicApp],
  exports: [...],
  entryComponents: [...],
  providers: [...]
});
export class AppModule {}
```

app.component.ts

```
import { Locale, LocaleService, LocalizationService } from 'angular2localization';
...
export class MyApp {
  constructor( platform: Platform, public locale: LocaleService, public localization: LocalizationService ) {
    platform.ready().then( () => {
      this.locale.addLanguage('en');
      this.locale.addLanguage('fr');
      this.locale.useLocalStorage();
      this.locale.definePreferredLocale('fr', 'FR', 30);
      this.localization.translationProvider('./i18n/locale-');
      this.localization.useLocaleAsLanguage();
      this.localization.updateTranslation();
      console.log(this.locale.getCurrentCurrency());  // Returns an empty string!
    }
  }
}
```

I don't understand why `this.locale.getCurrentCurrency()` always returns an empty string. It should return the default currency for the locale's country.
It seems that locale data are not present in Angular2localization.

So how to make locale data loaded (globally if possible) in my Ionic 2 app?

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if you've already solved, anyway missing initialization of currency:

```
// Optional: default currency (ISO 4217 three-letter code).
this.locale.definePreferredCurrency('EUR');
```

See also this [explanation](https://github.com/robisim74/angular2localization/blob/master/doc/spec.md#3.3).

If you need other information, please open a issue directly on the repo, so I see it right away.

Greetings